# My circular slider doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried including a circular slider into my app. I downloaded the files and tried to implement them, but the slider doesn't appear. He doesn't seem to give an error somewhere.

```
 <html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/circular-slider.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/circular-slider.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var circularSlider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
        min : 0,
        max: 359,
        value : 10,
        labelSuffix: "°",
        slide : function(value) {
            ui.next().css({'background' : 'linear-gradient(' + value +
            'deg, white, cornsilk, white)'});
        }
    });
</script>
</head>


 <body>
 <main>
  <div id="slider"></div> //this is where it should appear
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the "Circular Slider" plugin you're using so whoever answers your question can look at its documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `$('#slider')` is `undefined` at the time of the call. Either wrap your entire script in a [document.ready callback](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or move your `<script>` tag just before the end of the `</body>` tag.

This should work:

```
<script>
    // Wait for the DOM to be ready so the `#slider` element exists at the time of the call
    $(function() {
        var circularSlider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
            min : 0,
            max: 359,
            value : 10,
            labelSuffix: "°",
            slide : function(ui, value) {
                ui.next().css({'background' : 'linear-gradient(' + value +
                'deg, white, cornsilk, white)'});
            }
    });
</script>
```

**LE:**
Also, this:
`slide : function(value)`
should be this:
`slide: function(ui, value)`.

Comment: It still doesn't show anything.      `<script>
                      $( document ).ready(function() {
           console.log( "ready!" );



        $(function() {
            var circularSlider = $('#slider').CircularSlider({
                min : 0,
                max: 359,
                value : 10,
                labelSuffix: "°",
                slide : function(value) {
                    ui.next().css({'background' : 'linear-gradient(' + value +
                    'deg, white, cornsilk, white)'});
                }
            });

        });

    </script>`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the `console`? Also, where is the `ui` variable declared? See my edit.